# N>Help, Can't Login to Patch Organization

Tags: managed-package, push-upgrade, patch

I already have a managed package and I'm trying to do "push upgrades". I already did most of the steps needed but I'm stuck on the patch organization part.

Here is the screenshot of where I am now:
[image]

My problem is when I click on the link sent to my email, I am just redirected to the developer account. I think what should have happened is that I would be redirected to login to my patch org where I will be prompted for a new password. I already made other patch orgs (shown on the screenshot) but every time I clicked **Login**, it's still the same(**Just redirected back to the developer home page**). I **already read salesforce help docs** and followed them.

Can anyone please tell me if I miss anything significant to make it work as it is supposed to?

Answer (score 3):

You will have a separate login for each of your patch orgs, the username will be different for each one.

When you log in to a patch org. the black bar in the top right will say:

**Developing , version 1.XX'** (for example)

as opposed to:

**'Developing , version 1.X**' in your main package org.

When you spin up a new patch org, you get to specify a username & email address. You then should have the regular login confirmations mail as normal.

Are you sure you're using the correct link? Possibly a browser / autofill / password manager issue at play?

Worst case scenario, raise a case with Salesforce with the affected usernames and they will help you gain access easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have "My Domain" turned on, it looks like this is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XhsAAE) with Salesforce. One of the suggested workarounds is to "Disable My Domain in the mail patch org until this issue is addressed."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an org which had enabled "My domain". As @mralexlau mentions, this seems to be a know issue (apparently to be fixed on Winter'17). I used the workaround manually replacing the domain name with the org's instance in the link sent for password reset:

Original link (which redirects to the same home page of the org)

> https://[my-salesforce-domain].salesforce.com/?c=[random-chars...]

Link modified/workaround:

> https://[my-SFDC-org-instance].salesforce.com/?c=[random-chars...]

You can check your org's instance with [this tool](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/domainLookupLaunch/)